# ERROR in Resolution Merge using ERDAS IMAGINE 2013

Tags: erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing, pansharpening

I have attached an example image to show the problem: [image]When i have to Resolution Merge, it will come error this process. How to solve this problem? I would like some suggestions regarding this error.

Answer (score 1):

Well...it is exactly what it is reporting. You are running out of storage space on your harddrive. In addition to the results of a resolution merge being quite large, this model writes several temporary files to disk and requires a large amount of storage space in the scratch space, which defaults to your temp directory on C:/.

Comment: Dear Jeffrey, Thanks to replay. I changed preference settings even though that same error will come disk space 212 GB are available.